# How to update and assign an array of object to a new variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an array of object which looks like ->

```
const test - [{id: '1', marks: '32'},{id: '2', marks: '31'},{id: '3', marks: '12'}]
```

Now, here I am trying to update this array of object so that I want to add one more key value in each object.

```
setPrevious = test => {
    const {
      nav: {
        queryParams: { bspId }
      }
    } = stores
    const copyTest = _.cloneDeep(test)
     this.productCommentsAdded =  copyTest?.forEach(marks => {
      marks.productId = bspId
    })
  }
  
  setPrevious(test)
```

with this, sets the this.productCommentsAdded  to undefined . So, what is the proper way to do this ? update it and assign to that variable

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` does not return anything, so that would cause productsCommentsAdded to always end up as undefined. (If copyTest is undefined, that would also cause this, so that may be another issue to look into.) But assuming that copyTest is defined, one approach is to use `map` here to achieve what you want, like this:

```
    this.productCommentsAdded = copyTest?.map(marks => {
      return {...marks, productId: bspId};
    })
```

This creates a new array, containing a copy of each object in `copyTest`, (using the object spread operator, which is what the `...` part is called), and adds a new property `productId` to each of those new objects. The original copyTest array objects are unchanged; the new array with the new properties is returned by `map` and assigned to `this.productCommentsAdded`.
More info on `map`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

If you don't care whether or not the original copyTest array's objects are modified, you can also do this with forEach as follows:

```
    copyTest?.forEach(marks => {
      marks.productId = bspId;
    })
    this.productCommentsAdded = copyTest;
```

but the first way with `map` is generally a better practice (less likely to be surprising bugs due to mutating the original array's elements.)